# PHP / MySQL formatinng: An example of how this type of data is used?

Tags: php, mysql, database, storage, data-retrieval

Sorry in advance for the kind of odd/vague question :).  I've come across this kind of formatting stored in MySQL databases on several occasions now and I'm wondering how the data is used?  For example, this line of code was from the bbPress forums plugin bb_message.

a:8:{s:9:"max_inbox";i:50;s:13:"auto_add_link";b:1;s:9:"email_new";b:1;s:11:"email_reply";b:1;s:9:
"email_add";b:1;s:13:"email_message";b:0;s:16:"threads_per_page";i:0;s:7:"version";s:3:"1.0";}

What's up with the characters and letters?  For example I'm guessing s:9:"max_inbox" refers to a string of nine characters and the string is max_inbox.  But how is this data manipulated with PHP (and why would the s:9 be necessary)  when its pulled from the database?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's `unserialize` function to decode the strings like that.

[unserialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) PHP docs

This string decodes to this array like so:

```
php > $f='a:8:{s:9:"max_inbox";i:50;s:13:"auto_add_link";b:1;s:9:"email_new";b:1;s:11:"email_reply";b:1;s:9:"email_add";b:1;s:13:"email_message";b:0;s:16:"threads_per_page";i:0;s:7:"version";s:3:"1.0";}';
php > var_dump(unserialize($f));
array(8) {
["max_inbox"]=>
int(50)
["auto_add_link"]=>
bool(true)
["email_new"]=>
bool(true)
["email_reply"]=>
bool(true)
["email_add"]=>
bool(true)
["email_message"]=>
bool(false)
["threads_per_page"]=>
int(0)
["version"]=>
string(3) "1.0"
}
```

The reason for storing data like this is that you can store multiple parameters in one database field.

Storing serialized arrays allows you to not worry about the schema of your database. Friendfeed does this with MySQL for instance, and it's also similar to the style of the 'NoSQL' storage systems like MongoDB.  I prefer to use JSON over PHP serialize, myself.

Comment: Yes, it's the newline char you copied from OP's question. Just before "email_add" ;-)

Comment: Thanks,  I see now that in the PHP CLI that was just showing up as a space. I'll update with the decoded info!

Comment: thanks for the help.  And yeah sorry about the line break :)  This helps put me in the right direction.  If I could rate you both up I would!

Comment: Sure, you can rate both of our posts up actually if they were helpful, and then it's good to choose the one you like the best for the Accepted answer for your question.

Comment: oh no I just can't 'up' you both yet because I don't have 15 rep points, haha.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a string that is generated by PHP's serialize function. This function enables you to represent a (complex) object or array as a string.

Furthermore I think the numbers you are refering to are probably needed to make tokenizing (not sure if that is the appropriate term here) the string back to it's relevant parts easier. Without having given it much thought, I presume it is meant to circumvent situations where the tokenizer might choke on actual values of the serialized object that contain delimiters (:;").

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.  Who knows how long a newb programmer like me would of spent trying to figure out that's what serialized data looked like :).  I appreciate it!